# How do I find the biggest file in a folder and subfolders on the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line

I tried this command:

```
dir /s /a:-d /o:-s /b
```

However this command gives the biggest file hierarchy wise. For example, first it gives the biggest file in the main folder and listed out other files, then the biggest file in the subfolder. I need the biggest file on the top whether it is in the folder or subfolder.

Comment: you can view the folders and subfolders through following command      tree (drive letter :) e.g tree c:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got the solution. Here it is:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set tes=0
set name=
set path=

for /r %%h in (*.*) do (
IF !tes! LSS %%~zh (
SET tes= %%~zh
SET name= %%~nh
SET path= %%~ph
)
)

echo name = !name! >> Biggest.txt
echo size = !tes! >> Biggest.txt
echo path = !path! >> Biggest.txt
```

Comment: This does not work, at least for me. The problem is that in the If-condition, !tes! is never updated and stays the initial 0. Thus, the last processed file is being returned as the result.

Answer (score 20):

PowerShell can do this very easily:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\SomeParentDirectory" -Recurse | Sort-Object -Descending Length
```

Comment: Use the following command to get first 10 biggest files: Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\folder" -Recurse | Sort-Object -Descending Length | select-object -first 10

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
dir /b /o-s>{temp}
set /P biggest=<{temp}
del {temp}
ren "%biggest%" the_biggest_file_here
```

click [here](http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=123506.0) for more details

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to be more appropriate to the question, instead of copying the source directly. The URL you provided talks about renaming the largest file in a directory.

Comment: This gives the biggest file only in the current folder. I need to get the biggest file if it is there in the subfolder of the current folder